# Inverting the logarithm rule for quotients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In school I have been taught that $\log_a\frac{r}{s} = \log_ar - \log_a{s}$. Furthermore, it has been said that this rule can be inverted (applied from the right to the left). Then, I came across this:

> Simplify $\lg(x-y) - \lg(y-x)$.

Note that $\lg(x)$ means $\log_{10}(x)$. Let's consider $x, y \in \mathbb R^+$.

The "simplification" yields $\lg\frac{x-y}{y-x} = \lg(-\frac{y-x}{y-x}) = \lg(-1) \space\space\space ( = \frac{\ln(-1)}{\ln(10)} = \frac{\pi i}{\ln(10)})$.

However, if you look at the task, you would get different results depending on whether $x > y$ or $y > x$. (try it with a calculator or simply google an example...) So, is this rule wrong or do I have to make these "case differentiations" every time I am using this rule?

Comment: Use \mathbb R for the Real numbers set sign. The sign you have chosen is different. (Real part)

Comment: Do you know why $\ln(-1)=\pi i$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal $\mathbb e ^ {\mathbb i \pi} = -1$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal This is not actually part of the question, is it?

Comment: Do you understand that $\log$ is a multi-valued function?

Comment: @Hurkyl I see it now. What does that imply for the simplifications?

Comment: If you are dealing in Reals, then the answer would be $0$ because only when $x=y$, the function will be satisfied. Otherwise it would be complex.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where there are two seemingly different expressions that express the same value.  $\mathbb e ^ {\mathbb i \pi} = -1$ and $\mathbb e ^ {-\mathbb i \pi} = -1$.  Both are valid solutions to $\lg\frac{x-y}{y-x}$ and which one you arrive at depends on how you break down your expression.